# How can I indent all text after the label in my example environment

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs

I have built my own `example` environment for a paper I am working on. I have created a counter to label the resulting blocks of text. Now I want to indent the Text after the label, like so:

```
(1)   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Nullam hendrerit tempor purus in interdum. Ut nec augue
      ipsum.

(2)   Sed volutpat aliquet mauris non porta. Vivamus sagittis
      ante dapibus tellus vehicula ullamcorper. Quisque tris-
      tique commodo nisi et semper.

...

(10)  Sed volutpat aliquet mauris non porta. Vivamus sagittis
      ante dapibus tellus vehicula ullamcorper. Quisque tris-
      tique commodo nisi et semper.
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
\newcounter{examplectr}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]{
    \ignorespaces
    \refstepcounter{examplectr}
    (\theexamplectr)
    \hfill
}{}
```

But unfortunately, the resulting output looks more like this:

```
(1)   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nullam hendrerit tempor purus in interdum. Ut nec augue ipsum.

(2)   Sed volutpat aliquet mauris non porta. Vivamus sagittis
ante dapibus tellus vehicula ullamcorper. Quisque tristique
commodo nisi et semper.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer builds closely on the OP's original code, only adding some low-level TeX code in the preamble to set the width of the hanging indents. Basically, it defines a length variable called `\alength` and then sets its value to the width of a "box" filled by "`(\theexamplectr)`" (plus a minute fudge factor, determined empirically). The environment `example` is instructed to hang-indent all but the first line of its paragraph by the amount of `\alength`. Note that the amount of the indent is adjusted automatically as the counter variable switches from 1 to 2, 3, etc digits.

This code is, by design, not as "elegant" as simply setting some of the options of the `enumitem` package. In contrast, it has the advantage (IMHO) of not depending on this package and, instead, demonstrating how one may go about achieving the OP's objective by setting the `\hangafter` and `\hangindent` parameters. :-)

Addendum: I edited the code, following the OP's comment, to allow the possibility that the maximum number of examples is known in advance, so that the bodies of the examples may all be set to the same (hanging) indent. This is implemented by defining a `counter` variable named `maxexamplectr`; if this variable is greater than zero, its value is taken to be the largest number of any example environment. Conversely, if its value is zero the value of the hang-indent is calculated separately for each label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ifthen}

\newcounter{maxexamplectr}  %% largest possible number of examples
\setcounter{maxexamplectr}{1002} 

\newcounter{examplectr} %% counter of current example environment
\setcounter{examplectr}{0}  %% initialize this counter

\newlength\alength   

\makeatletter
% if maxexamplectr>0, calculate \alength only once 
\ifthenelse{\themaxexamplectr>0}{
    \sbox\@tempboxa{(\themaxexamplectr)\ \ }
    \setlength{\alength}{\the\wd\@tempboxa}}{}

\newenvironment{example}{%
    \refstepcounter{examplectr}%
    \ifthenelse{\themaxexamplectr=0}{% calculate \alength if maxexamplectr=0
       \sbox\@tempboxa{(\theexamplectr)\ \ }
       \setlength{\alength}{\the\wd\@tempboxa}}{}
    % start a "generic list" with a single, numbered item
    \begin{list}{{}(\theexamplectr)}%
       {\leftmargin\alength
        \labelwidth\alength
        \topsep0pt}
        \ignorespaces\item }
{\unskip \end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
The quick brown fox \ldots

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\setcounter{examplectr}{20}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\setcounter{examplectr}{1001}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\noindent
The quick brown fox \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: really not bad, i like this approach! i'm really learning a lot this way. but one of my big problems remains: the paragraphs that are numbered with a two-digit-number have a deeper indentation than the paragraphs that are numbered wit only one digit. so one would have to measure the width of the _last_ label and then indent all example environments this deep. is that possible?

Comment: To answer your question: If one knows in advance what the widest numeral label is going to be, one could account for that in two ways. First, one could redefine the example env to accept as an optional input the widest possible label. But this becomes tedious if you have, say, 105 examples and must provide the width of the widest label to the first 99 examples. Second, you could define a "special variable" in the preamble; if it is defined, it is the largest numeral that may be encountered. The example code tests for the presence of this variable and uses it to calculate the hangindent width.

Comment: I've adjusted the MWE above to incorporate the second possibility described in the preceding comment.

Comment: i must admit that i like this solution better than Gonzalo's so i accepted yours instead. thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you liked my solution! :-) By the way, in case you haven't already figured this one out on your own, you can add a labeling instruction, such as `\label{ex:some}`, after any of the `\begin{example}` instructions and then create a cross-reference to that example environment, somewhere else in the document, with the command `\ref{ex:some}`. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 11):

Using the `enumitem` package you can easily create a list-like environment to achieve the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{example}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[example,1]{label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=*,resume,ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: you can wrap the list-like environment inside another one, using the `series=`, `resume= options`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{example}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[example,1]{label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=*,ref=\arabic*}
\newenvironment{myexample}
  {\begin{example}[series=lafter,resume=lafter]\item}
  {\end{example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myexample}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add the options `resume` to `\setlist[example,1]` to achieve the same functionality as the environment of the question.

Comment: sorry, i think i didn't make clear enough, that there will be paragraphs between the examples! so this won't work i guess...

Comment: @padde: why not? Using the resume option you can end the environment, write your paragraphs, and then continue with the environment. See my updated answer

Comment: plus, when `\ref`ing to an item i get `Now i refer to Example (1)` instead of `Now i refer to Example 1`, which is what i need.

Comment: @padde Then add the options `ref=\arabic*` to `\setlist[example,1]`.

Comment: @padde: again, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo sounds good, but doesn't work for me, unfortunately :( i have to wrap the list in another environment which seems to break the counters somehow... (edit: actually i can achieve my goal without using an extra environment)

Comment: @padde: without some more information, and a minimal example, showing your real intent is really hard to guess what you're trying to do. Please, add complete information to your questions.

Comment: @Gonzalo you really helped a lot! thanks for your quick answers!

Comment: btw: i wanted to wrap all that in another environment in order to not having to type `\item` every time i begin an example. is that easily possible?

Comment: @padde: of course it is. See the EDIT to my answer

Comment: @padde: you're welcome! Don't forget to up-vote and accept the answer that you consider to be the one which best answers your question.

Comment: uh i was probably cheering to soon: your above example does not compile for me (computer says: `13: Package keyval Error: series undefined`). are you able to compile it? does one have to declare the series before using it?

Comment: @padde: you need a recent version (3.0) of the `enumitem` package. Update your version of the package.

Comment: that solved the problem. thanks, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution using `ntheorem` and the `changepage` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{marginjustnumber}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{(##2) }]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{(##2)} (##3)]}%
\makeatother

\newlength{\examplelabel}
\theoremstyle{marginjustnumber}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremprework{%
\settowidth{\examplelabel}{(\themyexample)\quad}%
\begin{adjustwidth}{\examplelabel}{}}
\theorempostwork{\end{adjustwidth}}
\newtheorem{myexample}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myexample}
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myexample}
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[3]
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the paragraphs do not align any more, when the number of examples is 10 or higher. is it possible to achieve that with this package? the rest is exactly as i want it!

Comment: You could try changing the line `\begin{adjustwidth}{\examplelabel}{}}` to `\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{}}` (or some similar length)